# How to drag and drop into iFrame from parent webpage?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a browser extension that injects an iframe into the webpage. Now the iframe elements are not responding to drag and drop events for webpage's elements though it is responding to drag and drop events from it's(iframe's) elements only. I've tried almost every solution but they didn't work. Can you give me any clue on how to fix this?
**The iframe is built using reactjs**

Comment: Look for examples of doing drag-n-drop over a cross-origin iframe. The usual workaround is to add a transparent div in the main page that's above the iframe and it'll get the events.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for your suggestion.